# Removing a border line from an element in a website

Tags: html, css, border

I am struggling to remove the line from my vertical menu of my website http://propertypricesearch.com/ (there is a vertical line)

I tried to inspect element and it seems to be `.vertical_area_background` class

```
.vertical_area_background{
    position: fixed;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #1d2022;
}
```

There i put lines like

```
right: 0px;

border-right-width: 0px !important;
```

but still its showing the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspected with Chrome and found the rule causing the line. Override it like this:

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on  .vertical_menu_area {
  border-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i tried to find the line body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on  .vertical_menu_area { but couldnt find.

Comment: @info Here's the file containing it. If you can't update this file, you can still paste the CSS I wrote elsewhere in your styles to apply it. http://propertypricesearch.com/wp-content/themes/burst/css/custom_css.css?ver=1481989539

Comment: Your website embeds a minified version of your stylesheet. You did not add the line to the CSS file that is actually being used: http://ahmed-mukhtar.com/wp-content/themes/burst/css/stylesheet.min.css?ver=4.7

Comment: By inspecting your web page using Chrome Developer Tools and seeing where the CSS rules are coming from. See: http://i.imgur.com/ZzoEUEd.png

Comment: Thanks. I removed that. I installed a plugin and messed up i think. I have put the rule in the theme css section but still line shows https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyoysu1yiwc6c2y/12.PNG?dl=0 . website is ahmed-mukhtar.com

Comment: There's one more border now that needs to be overwritten. Add this rule, too: `.vertical_area_background { border-right: 0 !important; }`

Comment: Thanks. https://www.dropbox.com/s/el3uwwrl2qpio7h/33.PNG?dl=0 Did it. Same line appears :(

Comment: @info You're missing the dot before `.vertical`

Comment: I am new here in wordpress editing and css. I have an idea how css work and how to edit it but i dont know how to inspect it. Can you share some ways or resources to help me or others to inspect and customize the css like you did?

Comment: @info Start here with the Elements heading: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You have a border on this element,

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area
```

**Solutions**

Change this,

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}
```

**1.**

```
 body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area {
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
         border-right: none !important;

    }
```

**2.**

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     border-right: 0 !important;

}
```

**3.**

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}
```

Basically each one of those options is either removing the rule or overriding it with `!important`

If you have access I would just delete the rule. If you must override it then I would add a new rule to my css that looked like this,

```
body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area {
         border-right: none !important;

    }
```

The difference between using `border-right: 0;` and `border-right: none;`

> border: none; However, the line-style value of none will cause
>   the color and width values to be ignored as stated in the CSS
>   Specification: 'none' No border. Color and width are ignored (i.e.,
>   the border has width 0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I pressed Control + F to find body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area but couldnt find . how to I access this line?

Comment: Just add the last rule I showed you in my answer to your style sheet. Make sure the !important flag is in the rule just like I write it.

Comment: Try removing body from the front of the rule so try starting the rule with .vertical etc

Comment: Also your probably using a Wordpress site. There is probably a menu inside the Wordpress dashboard that allows you to add custom CSS. You will most likely need to find the place in your theme that takes custom CSS and add it there.

Comment: You are right. i m using wordpress. yes there is an option. i will try to put now

Comment: In that case copy the rule exactly as I wrote it in my answer and put it in the custom CSS. If that fixes it up vote and accept my answer thanks :)

Comment: body.vertical_menu_background_opacity_over_slider_on .vertical_menu_area <--- This was in the custom css. I think i used some plygin for css editor and this rule was there. I removed it and put your css but still doesnt remove the line

Comment: Man it's really hard to help without seeing it. If you want I'd be happy to fix it for you I'm pretty experienced with Wordpress. You can skype me if you want. I'll be home in an hour and I could do it.  Check my profile for contact details and let me know. Otherwise all I can tell you is check to see that he CSS is being applied and if not trouble shoot to find out why

Comment: Also you might have a child theme set up and this could be causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also put a border: none  or border-right: none on that particular div holder, instead using the !important

```
<aside class="vertical_menu_area with_scroll " tabindex="5000" style="overflow-y: hidden; outline: none; border-right: none;">
```